# Is the OP on mushrooms?

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

What two words am I looking for in the puzzle below? (The title too is a clue).

*35437*

*When a Deity sees its reflection,*

*Clip the best of rediscoveries approximately.*

*Blow has been blown when it is done below the belt,*

*Being confused with the quartet's sound,*

*Making a faux faith, inside the ingredients of purée for gentlemen only.*

Hint:

> Clues 1 and 4 are not using the standard cryptic formula. Final clue is?!

> There is a final cryptic clue you are looking for.

Comment: Are you sure that these fit the normal structure of cryptic clues -- that is, they have a definition and wordplay, both independently letting you arrive at the answer?

Comment: (I ask because, for example, the first line looks like it might be `DOG<`, but there's no definition. It's fine if this puzzle doesn't follow the usual rules, or if you don't want to say. But the reason those rules are there is to make the clue fair and gettable; and if the puzzle doesn't follow them, the [cryptic-clues] tag might be more misleading than helpful.)

Comment: Well some of them do have the classic structure some don't.

Comment: Alright - it still might be a bit misleading for people expecting regular cryptic clues (even if it is technically applicable). And I'd warn you that the rules are there for a reason - without them, the clue can very easily become unfair. (You're not *disallowed* from using cryptic-style wordplay without that structure -- Hugh Meyers has done it very successfully in some of his riddles -- but you have to be very careful to make it fair.)